# Visual Studio 2008 Bug in <algorithm>? includes algo seems to inadvertently swap the order of iterators on line 3795

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I'm trying to get the `includes` algorithm to work on a `set` and `map` by comparing the map's keys to the set's values. The issue that needs to be circumvented is of course that `map<K,V>::value_type` is `pair<K,V>` while `set<V>::value_type` is `V` so these are not going to work with the default `includes predicate<T>` which expects the same value type for both arguments.

I am hence writing the below predicate classes to get around this

```
template <class P,class K>
struct mapKey_set_less : public std::binary_function<P,K,bool>
{
   inline bool operator() (const P& x, const K& y) const {return x.first < y ;};
};

template <class K,class P>
struct set_mapKey_less : public std::binary_function<K,P,bool>
{
    inline bool operator() (const K& x, const P& y) const {return x < y.first ;};
};
```

However the template instantiator is throwing up on line 313 of the VS2008 xutility file

```
if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right))
```

with the message that it cannot convert parameter 1 from `const V` to `const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>`

This seems to be caused by line 3795 of the  file

```
if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, *_First2, *_First1))
```

where the first and second arguments seem to have been swapped
Compiling in Release Configuration gives the same error on line 3795, so it seems the Visual Studio implementation wants you to go through this code unless you tinker with whatever switch (if any) removes this '_DEBUG_LT_PRED' macro.

My question is:
Is this a bug in Visual Studio or is there a reason for this to be this way and I am making a mistake? I haven't done any C++ in over a decade and had to pick up last week to get some speed ups in some tight loops so need all the help I can get.

Thanks all

Nice,

I didn't think about the requirements of the algo. Makes sense it needs to check "less than" from both sides.

Not getting much joy getting this to compile though.

With my previous code of

```
template <class P,class K>
struct mapKey_set_cmp //: public std::binary_function<P,K,bool>
{
    inline bool operator() (const P& x, const K& y) const {return x.first < y ;};
};
```

I was getting

```
error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_cmp<P,K>::operator ()(const P &,const K &) const' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const double' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'
```

which makes sense as there is no operator() that can take a double as its 1st argument.

With the additional overloaded operator()

```
template <class P,class K>
struct mapKey_set_cmp //: public std::binary_function<P,K,bool>
{
    inline bool operator() (const P& x, const K& y) const {return x.first < y ;};
    inline bool operator() (const K& x, const P& y) const {return x < y.first ;};
};
```

I am now getting

```
error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_cmp<P,K>::operator ()(const K &,const P &) const' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const double &'

error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_cmp<P,K>::operator ()(const K &,const P &) const' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const double &'

error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_cmp<P,K>::operator ()(const K &,const P &) const' : 
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const double' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'

error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_cmp<P,K>::operator ()(const K &,const P &) const' : 
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const double' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'
```

Of note is that all the errors seem to reffer to the 2nd `operator()`, the one with the `K` 1st and `P` 2nd. And yes, none of the conversions mentioned should be possible on that operator. But why isn't the compiler trying the other operator? ie the one on which those conversions should be allowed. (BTW the errors are repeated because they each occur on two different lines in case you are wondering)

Another thing this could be is of course const incorrectness. It's been a while so I'll try to think that through.

Thanks for the help

**Edit on 15 May 2013**

I had to "get on with it" so circumvented this problem by puting my map Keys into a set so that I could call the `includes` algo on two sets (incurring the obvious performance penalty). **I would still like to solve this properly though**. Here is all the code neded to replicate the compiler error I am describing with Visual Studio 2008

```
template <class PAIR,class KEY>
struct mapKey_set_less : public std::binary_function<PAIR,KEY,bool>
{
    inline bool operator() (const PAIR& x, const KEY& y) const {return x.first < y ;};
    inline bool operator() (const KEY& x, const PAIR& y) const {return x < y.first ;};
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    map<string,double> theMap;
    theMap["arse"] = 1;

    set<string> theSet;
    theSet.insert("arse");

    typedef map<string,double>::iterator MI;
    MI mi(theMap.begin()), miend(theMap.end());

    typedef set<string>::iterator SI;
    SI si(theSet.begin()), siend(theSet.end());

    typedef mapKey_set_less< pair<string,double>,string> cmp;

    if (includes(mi,miend,si,siend,cmp()))
    {}

}
```

The compiler spits out

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_less<PAIR,KEY>::operator ()(const KEY &,const PAIR &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const std::string &'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility  346
Error   2   error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_less<PAIR,KEY>::operator ()(const KEY &,const PAIR &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const std::string &'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility  348
Error   3   error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_less<PAIR,KEY>::operator ()(const KEY &,const PAIR &) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility  346
Error   4   error C2664: 'bool mapKey_set_less<PAIR,KEY>::operator ()(const KEY &,const PAIR &) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility  348
```

Looking at the 1st error alone it seems that it wants to use the operator()(KEY,PAIR) to pass in PAIR,KEY. Why is it ignoring the available operator()(PAIR,KEY)???
The other errors are all in the same vein, the compiler "appears" to ignore a perfectly good overloaded operator

Thanks all for the help

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did you really just migrate this?

Comment: Please show the code where you are calling `std::includes`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement from the standard that objects from the first range will only be passed as the left hand argument of the comparison function, nor that objects in the second range will only be passed as the right hand argument.  So, what Visual Studio is doing is perfectly valid, and often necessary (see below).

What you can do is write a single functor that handles both cases:

```
template <class K,class P>
struct set_mapKey_less : public std::binary_function<K,P,bool>
{
    inline bool operator() (const K& x, const P& y) const {return x < y.first;};
    inline bool operator() (const P& y, const K& x) const {return y.first < x; }
};
...
std::map<int,int> m;
std::set<int> s;

std::includes(m.begin(), m.end(), s.begin(), s.end(),
              set_mapKey_less<int,std::pair<int const,int> >());
```

To understand why the check that VS is doing might be necessary, consider the following:

```
set X = { 1000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 9000 }
map Y = { (3000,'a') }
```

How are you going to test whether X includes Y if all you have is an less than operator that takes a pair value on the left, and an integer on the right?

```
Is (3000,'a').first < 1000? No.
Is (3000,'a').first < 3000? No.
Is (3000,'a').first < 5000? Yes.
```

At this point, we know that `(3000,'a').first`, if in the set, has to be 3000.  But how do we test that it actually is 3000 with a comparator that can only take the pair on the left side?  If  we can reverse the arguments, we can do it:

```
Is 3000 < (3000,'a').first? No.
```

So now we know that `3000` is not less than `(3000,'a').first`, and `(3000,'a').first` is not less than `3000`, therefore they must be equal.

Comment: Minor nit: put a space between the ">>" - that's a C++11ism

Comment: Nice,

I didn't think about the requirements of the algo. Makes sense it needs to check "less than" from both sides.

Not getting much joy getting this to compile though.
I've added the details to the orginal question

Comment: The other thing is that if we are going to overload operator() both ways it could become confusing to inherit from `binary_function<P,K,bool>` as this prescribes that P be the 1st argument and K the 2nd. Not sure this makes much difference as I believe the definition of this class is just some typedefs but if those typedefs are being used by the stl I guess it could get confused. At any rate I have removed the inheritance. This has no apparent effect on the errors I get

Comment: Anyone had a chance to look at the compile errors I am getting?

Comment: @OldSchool: I looked at them when you posted them.  But I can't diagnose your code if I can't see it, which is why I made a comment beneath your question that you never responded to.